# how to invoke a jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery [autosuggest plugin](http://www.brandspankingnew.net/specials/ajax_autosuggest/ajax_autosuggest_autocomplete.html)

This is how plugin is implemented on the input field

```
var options = {
        script:"ajax/college.php?json=true&",
        varname:"college",
        json:true,
        callback: function (obj) { document.getElementById('college').value = obj.id; }
    };

    var as_json = new AutoSuggest('college', options);
```

this is how input field is appended to the page

```
 $('input[type=radio][name=career]').change(function() {
   if (this.value == '1') {
      $(".tp").html('<input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="college" id="college" placeholder="College name">');
     }
  });
```

but after appending plugin doesn't work on that input & if i just write the input field non dynamically then it works

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="college"
id="college" placeholder="College name">
```

Comment: where/when do you call the plugin?

Comment: @TomSarduy i just need to include the bsn.AutoSuggest_2.1.3_comp.js file and this var call the plugin `var as_json = new AutoSuggest('college', options);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin doesn't work because at the moment it is initialized, the `input` element with the id `college`does not exist in the DOM.

So, you need the initialize AutoSuggest script only after that `input` is inserted into the page.

Try the following code:

```
$('input[name=career]').change(function() {
    if (this.value == '1') {

        // check if autosuggest has not already been initialized
        if (typeof as_json === 'undefined') {

           // input element is inserted into the page
           $(".tp").html('<input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="college" id="college" placeholder="College name">');

           // initialize autosuggest here
           var as_json = new bsn.AutoSuggest('college', options);
       }

    }

});
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lhdcgg3o/.